Playing Sound From Bytes In Flutter
I typed a code in Python that creates a TCP server and to publish the system sound with my phone.
import socket
import soundcard as sc

def get_host_ip():
    try:
        host_name = socket.gethostname()
        host_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host_name)
        return host_ip
    except:
        return '127.0.0.1'

HOST = get_host_ip()
PORT = 1010

SAMPLE_RATE = 48000  
RECORD_SEC = 5       

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as server_socket:
    server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
    server_socket.listen()

    print(f"TCP Server is listening on {HOST}:{PORT}...")

    while True:
        conn, addr = server_socket.accept()
        with conn:
            print(f'Connected: {addr[0]}:{addr[1]}')

           
            with sc.get_microphone(id=str(sc.default_speaker().name), include_loopback=True).recorder(samplerate=SAMPLE_RATE) as mic:
                data = mic.record(numframes=SAMPLE_RATE * RECORD_SEC)
                conn.sendall(data[:, 0])


and for my phone I want to create a Flutter app that takes the bytes and plays. How can I do that and should I change the Python code?
I tried come codes in Internet and asked AI. But nothing.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
